# POST requests in Alamofire Parameter Encoding returning GET responses

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to make a Route Builder in swift using Alamofire (3.0) and I have succeded for all my GET requests, but when I try to make a POST request, for example, I still get the same responses of the GET method.

My API Routes are:

```
/users //GET -> return list of users
/users //POST -> create new user with the parameters sent
```

When I use Postman everything works fine.

Here is my Router code:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire


enum UserRouter: URLRequestConvertible{

    static let baseURL = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.0.106/users")!

    case Users
    case CreateUser([String: AnyObject])
    case ReadUser(Int)
    case UpdateUser(Int, [String: AnyObject])
    case DestroyUser(Int)

    var URL: NSURL { return UserRouter.baseURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(route.path) }

    var route: (path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?) {

        switch self{

        case .Users:
            return ("/", nil)
        case .ReadUser(let userID):
            return ("/\(userID)", nil)
        case .CreateUser(let userInfo):
            return ("/", userInfo)
        case .UpdateUser(let userID, let userInfo):
            return ("/\(userID)", userInfo)
        case .DestroyUser(let userID):
            return ("/\(userID)", nil)
        }

    }

    var method: Alamofire.Method{

        switch self{

        case .Users:
            return .GET
        case .ReadUser:
            return .GET
        case .CreateUser:
            return .POST
        case .UpdateUser:
            return .PUT
        case .DestroyUser:
            return .DELETE

        }

    }

    var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {

        let httpRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
        httpRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

        switch self{

        case .CreateUser (let userInfo):
            print("creating")
            print(httpRequest.HTTPMethod) //Print: POST on CreateUser, like it should.
            return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(httpRequest, parameters: userInfo).0
        default:
            return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(httpRequest, parameters: (route.parameters ?? [ : ])).0

        }

    }

}

func testRoute(){

   Alamofire.request(UserRouter.CreateUser(["name":"test"])).responseJSON{ (response) in

        switch response.result{

        case .Success(let data):
            print (data) //Error here, printing GET response instead of my API response for creating users (POST).
        case .Failure:
            print("fail")
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the problem was a combination of the command that `Alamofire.request()` generates (curl -i -X POST...) and how my Apache was handling trailing slashes of the URL. So when I tried to `POST "http://192.168.0.106/users"` I was being redirect (301) to a `GET "http://192.168.0.106/users"`.

So I had to include this line of command in my .htaccess:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

and change my Router's code, always appending a trailing slash at the end:

```
var route: String {

        switch self{

        case .Users:
            return ""
        case .ReadUser(let userID):
            return "/\(userID)/"
        case .CreateUser:
            return "/"
        case .UpdateUser(let userID):
            return "/\(userID)/"
        case .DestroyUser(let userID):
            return "/\(userID)/"
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will generate a JSON POST request. Are you sure your web service is expecting a JSON request? Make sure you don't conflate the fact that your web service returns a JSON response with the format of the request.

If your web service is expecting a standard POST request (i.e. a request with a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), you'd use `URL` for the `.CreateUser`, too:

```
var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {

    let httpRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
    httpRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

    switch self {
    case .CreateUser (let userInfo):
        return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(httpRequest, parameters: userInfo).0
    default:
        return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(httpRequest, parameters: (route.parameters ?? [ : ])).0
    }

}
```

If you ever have questions about whether the request was created correctly, I find that tools like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) can be useful in confirming the precise request that was sent to the web service.

Comment: Hello @Rob. It didn't work. I downloaded Charles and checked the requests. When using my app I got GET as the method and using Postman I got POST as the method. I used Laravel 5.2 to create my web service, I don't know if this is a relevant information.

Comment: Then, I'd suggest there's something else going on, beyond what you've included in your code sample. When I did `Alamofire.request(UserRouter.CreateUser(["name":"test"])). ...`, I got the proper `POST` request. This is why I jumped to the idea that your service might really have been expecting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request. BTW, in your Postman, did you send JSON request and get JSON response, or was the request `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? If your request is really intended to be JSON, then I'll delete this answer.

Comment: I took these screenshots of my requests, the first one is from the Postman:  [http://imgur.com/a/N2DMx](http://imgur.com/a/N2DMx). I really don't know what is going on. (I don't think you should delete your answer, Charles is a good tip)

Comment: My question was the `Content-Type` of the request. The Charles "Overview" tab shows us the `Content-Type` of the response. Click on the "Request" tab and either look at the raw content or the headers and confirm the `content-type` of the Postman's `POST` request. Compare and contrast to your Alamofire request.

Comment: In Postman I tried using `form-data` and `x-www-form-urlencoded`, and both I got the expected result. I don't think the problem is with the content-type since my app request is arriving as GET in my web service. Do you know how can I debug the request from Alamofire so I can check if it is leaving as a POST method ?

Comment: Use Charles and compare the raw request from the app vs that generated by Postman.

Comment: did also the `Content-Type` support `json` over your request? you are sending the data over json

Comment: try to print the request made, to check it sent a GET method

Comment: Ok. Now it is officially weird. `print(Alamofire.request(UserRouter.CreateUser(["name":"test"])))` prints `POST http://192.168.0.106/users/` Damn. Maybe it's some configuration of my apache or mac. I don't know. I'm lost here

Comment: @RenatoParreira - Yeah, when I examined the request via Charles, it's definitely a POST. There's something else going on in your environment. Good luck!

Comment: @Rob I've just downloaded an app in my iOS device to make HTTP requests and the POST request was successful. I'm back to thinking that the problem is my app. I also tried both PUT and DELETE methods with my app and they worked perfectly, I really have a problem only with the POST, and I'm getting out of ideas to debug this.