# What is the Alamofire equivalent of subclassing AFNetworking AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, alamofire

How does one create a shared API Manager using Alamofire with a base url, default headers, etc?

Comment: Completely different questions

Comment: D'oh! Misread the title. Sorry about that. It looked like the exact same title posted by the same person minutes apart. That's a pattern I see often when someone wants to get more attention for their post. I'll remove my suggested close vote. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think you're missing some of the Alamofire features and best practices. Alamofire is (by design) really coupled to the Swift coding practices. This includes avoiding a subclass, instead you have the Swift enum statement which works fine. Take a look on this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333241/proper-usage-of-the-alamofires-urlrequestconvertible

Comment: Maybe this is what you need http://eliasbagley.github.io/json/api/alamofire/2015/09/25/making-network-requests-with-alamofire.html